# Inserted image on panel's placeholder not rendering correctly

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have this weird problem regarding with an `xtype: 'image'` component added using `insert()` in a panel's placeholder:

Panel:

```
{
  xtype: 'panel',
  collapsed: true,
  region: 'east',
  collapsible: true,
  split: true,
  . . . 
  listeners: {
    afterrender: function (panel) {
      if (panel.placeholder) {
        panel.placeholder.insert(1,
          {
            xtype: 'image',
            src: 'myImage.png',
            margin: '10 0'
          }
        );
        panel.placeholder.setTitle('');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so problem is, the icon I added in the placeholder is not being displayed correctly, left is being set at 9px, when it should be 0:

[image: afterrender]

but after expanding the said panel and then collapsing it again, the image is correctly displayed. What could have been the cause? Am I doing the insert correctly?

**NOTE:** The margin config for the image is being used by Extjs to position the element. However, the `left` property of the image is being set at `9px`. I have tried: `margin: '10 0 10 0'` or even `margin: '10 5'` nor `margin: '10 5 10 5'` but still the image is being set `left: 9px` which makes me think that the `L/R` margins are not being accounted for. But when setting `margin: 10`, the `L/R` margins are being accounted.

**EDIT:** Here's a working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/25dh) for reference, as per @Tejas1991 request.

Try running the fiddle. as you can notice, the image of east panel is not correctly positioned. Now, try expanding the panel and then collapse it again. Voila!

Comment: Can you put running code inside sencha fiddle ?

Comment: what's the reason for downvote?

Comment: @Tejas1991, added fiddle. hope you can help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seems like you have to provide the `width` of the image in order for it to be correctly added to the placeholder.

```
panel.placeholder.insert(1, {
  xtype: 'image',
  src: 'myImage.png',
  margin: '10 0',
  width: 25
});
```

Comment: havent edited fiddle yet.. editing now.. thanks for reminding

Comment: @Tejas1991, done updating fiddle. please see for your own content.